# UWP WinRT: how to check if current app has focus

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I have a UWP C++ WinRT app and I am trying to handle a click event. While doing it, I want to confirm whether the current application has the focus. I checked GetForegroundWindow but it seems due to security this API is not available in WinRT. So how can I check if the current app has focus?

Comment: CoreWindow.ActivationMode

Comment: How would you do it in, say, C#?  How did the translation of that technique to C++/WinRT lead to a perplexing outcome?  Please edit you question to reveal what you tried like this.